# Is there a way to add discrete labels to plotly imshow images

Tags: python, plotly, label, imshow

I am using plotly to show an image using `fig=px.imshow(img)`

I would like it to have a discret legend similar to the ones in the pie chart or the bar chart: `fig2 = px.pie(df, values=df[0],names=df.index,color =df.index, color_discrete_map= h.colormap)`

`imshow()` does not have the argument `color_discret_map` but maybe there could be a work-around ?

I know it is possible with matplotlib but I need plotly to do it.

Comment: Maybe try using the graph_object library from plotly. There are more options.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66518387/python-plotly-graph-objects-discrete-color-map-like-in-plotly-express) might help you on how to do this with graph_object

Comment: The labels in the discret legend indicates to what in the image?

Comment: If you mean color there will be huge labels in the legend for each color in the image and that would be ineffective solution,